# Conditionally print debug info containing sensitive data

Tags: go, security, logging

I am running a Go program as a `k8s` job.

The application sends an API request to an `elasticsearch` cluster to [create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/security-api-put-user.html) users, therefore it will contain sensitive data (user's password).

```
    requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    responseDump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    esapiClient.log.Printf("got response code %d when creating user: %s\n", resp.StatusCode, user.Username)
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        esapiClient.log.Printf("error: got response code: %d when creating user %s\n", resp.StatusCode, user.Username)
        esapiClient.log.Println("Request\n", string(requestDump))
        esapiClient.log.Println("Response\n", string(responseDump))
        return ErrResponseCode
    }
```

When things go south, I want to be able to dump the request and the responses (especially in `400` cases) to check what went wrong (mainly with potentially malformed requests).

What is the recommended way of of doing this? Are log levels the only way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log levels is a non-solution. Your goal should be not having PII (personally identifiable information) end up in your log dumps altogether, including when you start the service in debug mode.

Depending on how you do the logging, just implement the relevant interfaces on your structs and omit or redact fields that contain PII. In case of fields where you need to have some clue about the original value for debugging purposes, you can redact only a part of it.

For example, if you log with `fmt` verbs or similar, you can implement the `Stringer` interface:

```
type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
}

func (u User) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{%s %s}", u.Name, "*****")
}


func main() {
    u := User{"pkaramol", "secret"}
    fmt.Println(u) // {pkaramol *****}
    
}
```

If you log in JSON, implement `MarshalJSON` to redact, or use the struct tag `json:"-"` to omit:

```
func (u User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "name": u.Name,
        "password": "*****",
    })
}

func main() {
    u := User{"pkaramol", "secret"}
    b, _ := json.Marshal()
    fmt.Println(string(b)) // {"name":"pkaramol","password":"*****"}
}
```

Comment: This seems the way to go. However since `httputil.DumpRequest` is very convenient, I don't know it will take into account my `MarshalJSON`. Will give it a try though

Comment: @pkaramol `httputil.DumpRequest` dumps whatever is on the wire. It should be used in development settings only, not in production. In production, just do regular logging with the appropriate sanitization.